# SVN: Is it possible to prevent commit on specific path?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

We are preparing to migration from SVN to GIT. All our projects (each of them has branches, tags, etc) are under one repository. During migration we would like to make some projects read-only. Is it possible to write SVN commit hook that would check if files have been changed under some specific path?

## Solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"

SVNLOOK=/opt/local/bin/svnlook

# Committing to migrated projects to GIT is not allowed
$SVNLOOK changed -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | grep "\/some_path\/" && /bin/echo "This repository is read-only due to migration to GIT. Please commit to GIT repo instead!" 1>&2 && exit 1

# All checks passed, so allow the commit.
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is easily possible.

In a `pre-commit` hook you get the path to the repo and the transaction name as parameters. You can then use `svnlook changed -t <transaction> <repo path>` to get a list of affected paths and fail the hook if a read-only path is to be updated.